# Edge browser refresh after closing the element - Angular 5

Tags: angular, microsoft-edge

I have two buttons on form

```
<button *ngIf="!loader" type="submit" class="custom-button blue left">Update</button>
<button (click)="close()" class="custom-button red left">Close</button>
```

Everything is working fine in Chrome but in Edge after I click on Close button my whole page is refreshed.

It my .ts file I have

```
export class InventoryDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() inventoryDetails: boolean;
  **@Output() inventoryDetailsChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();**
  @Output() update = new EventEmitter();

  close () {
    this.inventoryDetailsChange.emit(false);
  }
```

Any error I get in Edge is

> Unable to get property 'handleEvent' of undefined or null reference
>   polyfills.bundle.js (4262,17)

I can not figure out why is Edge crashing on this event

***The problem with this was with bad type on buttons, my both buttons were type='button' and that was confusing for EDGE, I added type='submit' for my submit button and that prevented my browser to crash***

Comment: Do you have a working page to repro against. Because the error page and the experience don't add up. The entire page refreshing seems like EdgeHTML is completely crashing and probably has nothing to do with that error as the above error doesn't look like an EdgeHTML crash stack. If you can provide me with a repro at bugs.microsoftedge.com we can get a trace and identify the root issue.

Comment: @gregwhitworth You were right!  I solved this bug by adding type to every button, type='submit' and type='button'  

Without your help I would not change my focus to html, thank you

Comment: mind filing a bug with a reduction of the crasher here: bugs.microsoftedge.com so we can get it fixed and other webdevs don't have to work around it?

Comment: I had an issue in my Angular 6 app where pages where refreshing when clicking on the buttons. type='button' has fixed the issues. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Generally the problem is that MS Edge submits the form whenever a button of type "submit" is clicked inside of any form. Which acually is understandable, but doesn't work very well in SPA applications, because it means refreshing a page.

The first possible answer was mentioned in comments and author added it inside of his question: change button type from "submit" to "button".

The second answer is to use `event.preventDefault()` in button's handler.

So in this case:

```
<button (click)="close($event)" class="custom-button red left">Close</button>
```

```
close (event) {
    event.peventDefault();
    this.inventoryDetailsChange.emit(false);
  }
```

Changing a button type is not always a good idea. E.g. if you would like your users to be able to submit a form only by using keyboard (clicking enter), you would need to have a submit button inside of your form.